# Fixing output to make it read properly instead of running a segmentation fail

Tags: c

Write a C program to split an input string (variable “name”) into two output strings (variables “first”
and “last”). Assume that the user provides input containing only the characters ‘a’ through ‘z’ and ‘A’
through ‘Z’. Assume there are exactly two capital letters in the input, one at the beginning of the first
name, and one at the beginning of the last name. For example, given the input “JoeSmith”, your code
should split it into “Joe” and “Smith”. If the given input contains only the first name example “Joe”
then it should print ‘only the first name is provided’ and print that first name.

```
int main() {
  char name[20], first[20], last[20];
  printf("Enter FirstLast name or enter First: ");
  scanf("%s", name);
  int i, j, index;
  for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      first[i] = name[i];
    } else {
      if (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z') {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
      first[i] = name[i];
    }
  }
  for (j = index, i = 0; i <= 20 - index; j++, i++) {
    last[i] = name[j];
  }
  first[i + 1] = '\0';
  last[j + 1] = '\0';
  if (first[i]) printf("Only first name printed%s\n", first);
  printf("first name:%s\nlast name:%s", first, last);
  return 0;
}
```

how would I get the code to print out "only first name printed" and print the first name beneath it? having trouble figuring this out. Also keeping the FirstLast name aswell.

When I input BobJoe

it prints

First name:Bob
Last name:Joe

Which is one of the two things I need^^

When I input

Bob

it prints

zsh: segmentation fault  ./run

Comment: Given `char name[20];` then `name[20]` in later code refers to an entry that does not exist & is an out-of bounds access. Don't do that. Indexes run from 0, so valid indexes for name are from 0 to 19, inclusive. `first[i + 1]` could be even further out of bounds.

Comment: @AviBerger how would I go about fixing that then?

Comment: @billyjoe2 Check if the char `first[index]` is  **not** capital right after the first `for` loop, and if so then print `Only first name printed` and return from the function.

Comment: How to fix it? You could start by changing your loop conditions so that your loops don't try to access 21 elements of 20 element arrays. ( <20 rather than <= 20 ) and adding additional tests as necessary.  And this isn't everything. Some additional problems are index is not always being initialized and you aren't checking for null terminators indicating shorter input strings. You have some work ahead of you to sort this out.

Comment: @AviBerger I see, I am sorry for asking.

Comment: You already know how to limit the loop iterations, you were just off by one. You also know if statements and conditions, so you already have the pieces to check if i + 1 is in bounds and try to do something else if it isn't. Its practice in using and thinking about these things that you need. Just do things a small piece at a time & use a debugger to see what is happening when things go astray.

Comment: @AviBerger I completely dumped the code, I am going to restart. thank you though for your help.

Comment: `scanf("%s", name);` is a disaster waiting to happen.  The behavior is undefined if the input stream contains 20 contiguous non-whitespace characters.  Always include a width modifier, in this case `scanf("%19s", name)` and check the return value: `if( scanf("%19s", name) != 1 ){ /* handle unexpected/invalid input */}`

Answer (score 0):

Trying out your code with regard to the comments made above, I offer up a revised version of your code utilizing the "string.h" include file to provide a bit better control.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20], first[20], last[20];

    int i = 0, j = 0, caps = 0, index;

    printf("Enter FirstLast name or enter First: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    for (index = 0; index < 20; index++)    /* Initialize the first and last name arrays to avoid unknown character data */
    {
        first[index] = '\0';
        last[index] = '\0';
    }

    for (index = 0; index < strlen(name); index++)
    {
        if (name[index] >= 'A' && name[index] <= 'Z')
        {
            caps++;
        }
        if (caps <= 1)
        {
            first[i] = name[index];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            last[j] = name[index];
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (last[0] == '\0')
        printf("Only first name printed: %s\n", first);
    else
        printf("first name: %s\nlast name: %s\n", first, last);
    return 0;
}
```

To ensure that the resulting first and last name arrays do not have uninitialized data, these are initialized prior to usage.  Then, in the program the "strlen" function is utilized to ensure that testing and copying does not run past the end of your input character array.

The result in testing these changes are as follows in the terminal output.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/FirstLast/bin/Release$ ./FirstLast 
Enter FirstLast name or enter First: JoeSmith
first name: Joe
last name: Smith
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/FirstLast/bin/Release$ ./FirstLast 
Enter FirstLast name or enter First: Joe
Only first name printed: Joe
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/FirstLast/bin/Release$ ./FirstLast 
Enter FirstLast name or enter First: joeSmith
Only first name printed: joeSmith
```

Give that a try to see if this meets the spirit of your project.